# Inserting Javascript at runtime, unable to access the variable

Tags: javascript, appendchild

I'm using javascript files to store lists of images and other stuff. I want to read one of these files at runtime, during page load and after clicking a button. I am able to load the javascript file as a script, but I can't immediately access its contents.

This is my solution to not being able to use javascript to load local files.

```
<script>
function Get_Slide_Show(Idx) {
  Raw_Album_Info = '';
  alert('Before: ' + Raw_Album_Info);
  albumPath = 'photos/' + albumList[Idx];
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = albumPath + '/album_info.js';
  // document.head.appendChild(script);
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
  alert('After: ' + Raw_Album_Info);
}

function Load_Slide_Show(Idx) {
  Get_Slide_Show(Idx);
  Load_Album_Info();
}

function Init_Slide_Show() {
  Load_Album_List("photos");
  Load_Slide_Show(0);
  showSlides();
}
</script>
```

Init_Slide_Show runs when the page loads.

Load_Slide_Show runs when the user clicks a button.

The problem is in Get_Slide_Show. It loads and appends the selected javascript file, which is simply something like

```
Raw-Album_Info = 'image1.jpg\n'+image2.jpg\n';
```

I reset Raw_Album_Info at the start and the first alert confirms this. I expected the second alert to show the new value for Raw_Album_Info. It doesn't.

If I remove the line

```
Album_Info = '';
```

then the second time I run Get_Slide_Show the alerts show the value from the previous call.

So I can read the variable, but I can't access it right away. Should I be using insertBefore, or calling some kind of refresh?

Comment: is your script in any kind of onDOMready function?

Comment: Your script is just putting the JS file into the header of your document. It's not doing anything else. You need to do an HTTP request in order to get the values, then extract the values in a loop if you want to read the file and get values from it. Album_Info is empty because you need to set it to something for the value to change.

Comment: I was using JS files in a recent project that did not involve a server. This one does. I should probably just go with httpRequests instead.

Answer (score 0):

Loading a script element occurs asynchronously, sometime after appending it to the document. The posted code is trying to access 
`Raw_Album_Info` before the script has loaded.

Try adding a load event handler to the script element to run code when after it loads -  can access the value of `Raw_Album_Info` in the handler for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

**Raw_Album_Info** is undefined until the document is done loading. You could do a document.readystate call or something, but below I use the function **updatetest()**, that uses setTimeout to keep calling itself until **Raw_Album_Info** is defined.

In the album_info.js, it helps to use the **slanted tick** ` (below the ~ key).  The ` tick goes before and after the text you want in your **var** declaration.  If you use the tick, its easy to write a short script that will automate creating the .js files from the original text files.  For example, if your original text file was album_info.txt, a bash script would look like this:

```
echo -n "var x=\`" > album_info.js
cat album_info.txt >> album_info.js
echo "\`" >> album_info.js
```

You had the wrong dash in the **Raw_Album_Info** variable in your question write up.  Maybe it was just a write up error, but if that error was actually in your album_info.js code, it would have prevented the **real** **Raw_Album_Info** variable from getting a result.
The contents of my album_info.js for testing (Note, using the tick to create the .js file also **preserves the linefeeds from your text file**, so you can use var.split('\n') in your code if you want to use an array):

```
var Raw_Album_Info = `image1.jpg
image2.jpg
`
```

For demo purposes, I created an albumList array at the top, and a script at the bottom to so it shows a popup with the variable contents.  I commented out the alerts as they are not needed for this demo.  I commented out **Raw_Album_Info=''** because it needs to be undefined initially for **updatetest()** to work correctly.

Contents of test.htm, tests OK in Firefox:

```
<script>
var albumList=["ipplr/","ipplr2/"] //my test paths

function Get_Slide_Show(Idx) {
  //Raw_Album_Info = '';          //do not set, leave as undefined
  //alert('Before: ' + Raw_Album_Info);
  albumPath = '/home/ken/temp/' + albumList[Idx];
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = albumPath + '/album_info.js';
  document.head.appendChild(script);
  //document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
  //alert('After: ' + Raw_Album_Info);
}

function Load_Slide_Show(Idx) {
  Get_Slide_Show(Idx);
  Load_Album_Info();
}

function Init_Slide_Show() {
  Load_Album_List("photos");
  Load_Slide_Show(0);
  showSlides();
}
</script>

<script>
Get_Slide_Show(0)
updatetest()

function updatetest()
{
  if (typeof(Raw_Album_Info)=='undefined'){
    setTimeout('updatetest()',500)  //call back until defined
  }else{
    //you can alert, or just write to console to verify
    alert(Raw_Album_Info)
    console.log(Raw_Album_Info)
  }
}
</script>
```